# how to hide android app downloaded files outside the app users

Tags: android

My android app download several files from app server. Users have to buy these files. So, i need to hide and encrypt these files, so that users cannot play/view these files, or they cannot delete/transfer these files. What are my options here?

Comment: Creating your own format so they can't read it, but I think a sqllite db would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this link: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

I would give a try for `SQLiteDatabase` keeping files as bytes (`BLOB` column type) or caching in internal storage

You may also keep files in external storage in hidden folder (name starting with dot, e.g. `.hiddenFolder`) if you are encrypting data, but note that every app can be decompiled and all methods/ciphers may be visible then (key fetched only from server without keeping localy?) and access to external storage (e.g. SD card) is easy when folder name is known (or intuitive, or get from decompiled source)

Answer (score 1):

Put those files in internal memory. No need for encryption then. Only if the device is rooted you are out of luck. Then you need encryption there too. Putting the files in a database unencrypted will fail on a rooted device too.